# VideoToolBox Framework is still disabled in XCode 6.0.1,who knows why?

Tags: ios, video

I've updated XCode to **6.0.1** recently,wanting to use its hardware decoding function in **VideoTool Box** framework,introduced in WWDC 2014,session 513. Unfortunately,I can't import any related header,such as `CMFormatDescription.h`.

Is there any one who has sucecessfully use these functions?

Comment: I don't know xcode very well, but you may need to update your project and set your minimum ios version to 8

Comment: @szatmary Thanks for your advice. I finally resolve this issue by adding CoreMedia and VideoToolBox framework to my Xcode project.Then I can see the headers and use these new APIs.